# Где можно скачать исходный код Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Comment: скажите зачем вам ? http://archive.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @eicto, как зачем?

Вот же  автор  пишет

    I prefer HTML5 and CSS3 most of all. I think great works will change our life.

на своем сайте.

Comment: это анекдот прям какой-то - человек немного владеет HTML и JS и полагает, будто что-то сможет понять в исходниках операционной системы. @baksis2, я вас удивлю, наверное,  но Linux (и, следовательно, Ubuntu) написан не на JavaScript

Comment: "DreamChild" Я наверно знаю, что он не написан на JavaScript. А что, по Вашему я не могу например выучить C? Почему по Вашему я не могу посмотреть например ядро Linux!? И Ваш комментарий в моём вопросе о моём сайте "Мой вам совет - не выпендривайтесь с английским - такое ощущение, что вы его знаете на уровне "london is the capital of great britain". Если без языка Шекспира ну прям уж никак, воспользуйтесь услугами человека, знающего его на достаточно хорошем уровне." Как раз говорит о том, что Вы сам не знаете английского, так как этот текст переводил профессионал.

Comment: @baksis2, [ядро Linux](https://www.kernel.org/) (а обижаться не стоит).

Если в самом деле интересуетесь ядром, можно сначала почитать книжку:

Роберт Лав. Ядро Linux. Описание процесса разработки.

Мне книга действительно понравилась (одна из немногих за последние лет пять).

Comment: Спасибо! Обязательно прочитаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt-get source linux-source-x.x.x
```

ничего не говорит?

Comment: ядра уже мало?

Comment: apt-get source ubuntu-desktop :D :D

Comment: @baksis2 А что такое по-вашему Ubuntu? Это просто набор пакетов.